# Issues with Powershell Import-CSV

Tags: powershell

Main Script

```
$Computers = Get-Content .\computers.txt

If ( test-path .\log.txt ) {
    $Log_Successful = Import-CSV .\log.txt | Where-Object {$_.Result -eq "Succesful"}
} ELSE {
    Add-Content "Computer Name,Is On,Attempts,Result,Time,Date"
}
$Log_Successful | format-table -autosize
```

Issues:

Log_Successful."Computer Name" works fine, but if i change 4 to read as the following

```
$Log_Successful = Import-CSV .\log.txt | Where-Object {$_.Result -eq "Failed"}
```

Log_Successful."Computer Name" no longer works... Any ideas why?

Dataset

```
Computer Name,Is On,Attempts,Result,Time,Date
52qkkgw-94210jv,False,1,Failed,9:48 AM,10/28/2012
HELLBOMBS-PC,False,1,Successful,9:48 AM,10/28/2012
52qkkgw-94210dv,False,1,Failed,9:48 AM,10/28/2012
```

Comment: Please use `Set-PSDebug -strict` in **every** script in order to catch misspelled variables.

Comment: In addition, the usual convention for Powershell keywords is to use lowercase. Prefer the .Net case when you use stuff from .Net libraries like `[Regex]::GetGroupNames()`. `IF{...}ELSE{...}` looks like SQL and `If{}...ELSE{}` looks just plain weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of "Successful" a single object is returned. It contains the property "Computer Name". In case of "Failed" an array of two objects is returned. It (the array itself) does not contain the property "Computer Name". In PowerShell v3 in some cases it is possible to use notation `$array.SomePropertyOfContainedObject` but in PowerShell v2 it is an error always. That is what you probably see.

You should iterate through the array of result objects, e.g. `foreach($log in $Log_Successful) {...}` and access properties of the `$log` objects.

And the last tip. In order to ensure that the result of `Import-Csv` call is always an array (not null or a single object) use the `@()` operator.

The code after fixes would be:

```
$logs = @(Import-Csv ... | where ...)
# $logs is an array, e.g. you can use $logs.Count

# process logs
foreach($log in $logs) {
    # use $log."Computer Name"
}
```

Comment: OMFG i love you!!!!! Thank you soo much, I have been playing with every combination I could think of for like 9 hours!! thank you, i would up-vote this a 100 times!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the problem but you have a typo, in Where-Object you compare against "Succesful" and the value in the file is "Successful" (missing 's').

Anyway, what's not working?